# How to find out if A contains B? In javascript

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, include, indexof

Let's say I have two divs A and B.

```html
<div id="A">1253555</div>

<div id="B">1</div>
```

I have to find out if A contains B.
In this example, it will be the answer of (if 1253555 contains 1 ), which should be true.
Then i have to execute function doSomething().

```js
function doSomething() {

  var x  =  document.getelementById("A").innerHTML;

  var y  =  document.getelementById("B").innerHTML;

  if (=...) { 
 // I dont know how to code here now...i tend to use indexof

}
```

Please guide me further.
Please use a method in pure javascript and works best for all browsers.

Comment: One thing, your `document.getelementById` needs to be `Element` not `element`

Answer (score 1):

Just use `includes`:

```
if(x.includes(y)){
  console.log('true');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "includes" method.

```
function doSomething() {
   var x  =  document.getElementById("A").innerHTML;
   var y  =  document.getElementById("B").innerHTML;

   if (x.indexOf(y) !== -1) {
    console.log("Perform your next task!!!")
   }
}

doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `String.prototype.includes(other)` function.
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
function doSomething() {

  var x  =  document.getElementById("A").innerHTML;

  var y  =  document.getElementById("B").innerHTML;

  if (x.includes(y)) console.log("It does");
  else console.log("It doesn't");

}

doSomething();
```

```html
<div id="A">1253555</div>

<div id="B">1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

more complete code...

```js
const bTest = document.getElementById('bt-test')
  ,  divA   = document.getElementById('div-A')
  ,  divB   = document.getElementById('div-B')
  ;
bTest.onclick=()=>
  {
  if ( divA.textContent.includes( divB.textContent ))
    alert( 'yes it include')
  else
    alert( 'nope!')
  }
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="div-A" contenteditable>1253555</div>

<div id="div-B" contenteditable>1</div>

<button id="bt-test"> test include </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is document.getElementById() (capitalize 'E' of Element), then you can use includes() string method in your conditional. Take care about security issues of innerHTML, you can use instead textContent, you can read about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML (security considerations section)

```js
  var x  =  document.getElementById("A").textContent;
  var y  =  document.getElementById("B").textContent;

  if (x.includes(y)) { 
    console.log('yes')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code concept is simple just get the div innerHTML value and use includes in the javascript you will get the result you wan : D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">1234</div>
    <div id="b">1</div>
</body>

<script>
    var a1 =  document.getElementById("a").innerHTML;
    var b1 =  document.getElementById("b").innerHTML;

    if(a1.includes(b1)) alert("true"); // you can change the alert to do whatever function you wan :D
    else alert("false");
</script>
</html>
```